# how to apply inline style in react component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am creating a react component having html progress bar and i am trying to apply inline style to it but it's not applying the linear-gradient to progress bar.

Here's a sample code

```
const customColor = '#d3d4d5'

const element = 
   <progress 
      max="100" 
      value="85"
      style={{ color: customColor,
               background: `linear-gradient(to left, #FF0000, #FF0000)`}}>
   </progress>

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Link to codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMGbGe?&editors=0010

Any idea why it wont apply linear-gradient to progress bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `<progress>` element in HTML5 doesn't yet support custom CSS for the fill and empty areas. See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-progress-value) for some experimental options.

An example from the docs:

```
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

You could try these in react, but they do not work in IE or Firefox. I would recommend a separate progress component.

Comment: I can get the output by creating css. The issue is its an existing component and i am thinking to update the same component instead creating new one. I just need to pass two props startColor and endColor and use them in linear-gradient. But are you saying its not possible or something? dont see on MDN docs anything saying gradient cant be used in inline style

Comment: It can via these expiremental css properties, but they are not set to be included in the standards, and the second most popular browser does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use `:progress-bar` and `:progress-value`. You can try:

```
progress {
  background: customColor;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #FF0000, #FF0000));
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: customColor;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #FF0000, #FF0000));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yoan Please check my reply to Nick